# Extract all URLs from CSV /Excel file and put it in a separate column

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, csv, url

I have a csv file. When I open the csv file in Microsoft excel, I have a column.

Each cell in the column has number of paragraphs. each paragraph has many URLs.

I am looking to extract all URLs in each cell of the column and put each URL in separate cell in a new separate column.

All URLs start with   http://   and finish with   .jpg

How can I do this in Excel or Notepad++

Thank you in advance

Comment: As I asked in your last question, please [edit] and provide before and after data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that will split cells with linefeeds into columns. You should be able to tweak it depending on what your paragraphs look like.

```
Sub SplitCellsAndExtend_New()
'takes cells with inside line feeds and creates new row for each.
'reverses merge into top cell.

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


Dim strCell As String, lastRow As Long, lRowLoop As Long, j As Long, arSplit
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Const lColSplit As Long = 4
Const sFirstCell As String = "A1"
Dim sSplitOn As String
sSplitOn = Chr(10)

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, lColSplit).End(xlUp).Row

    For lRowLoop = lastRow To 1 Step -1

        arSplit = Split(Cells(lRowLoop, lColSplit), sSplitOn)

        If UBound(arSplit) > 0 Then
            Rows(lRowLoop + 1).Resize(UBound(arSplit) + 1).Insert

            Cells(lRowLoop, lColSplit).Resize(, UBound(arSplit) + 1).Value = arSplit
            Cells(lRowLoop, lColSplit).Resize(, UBound(arSplit) + 1).Copy
            Cells(lRowLoop + 1, lColSplit).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

            Cells(lRowLoop, 1).Resize(, lColSplit - 1).Copy Cells(lRowLoop + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(arSplit) + 1)

            Rows(lRowLoop).Delete
        End If

        Set arSplit = Nothing
    Next


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I found this website http://www.convertcsv.com/url-extractor.htm which helps me to to extract URLs. I hope this will help someone.